# Linq if condition in where clause

Tags: linq

How to use if condition in where clause

```
public static void IfCondition()
    {
        var number = 10;
        var result =from ans in number where if(number < 5 )select "false" else select "true"  ;
    }
```

where i am going wrong please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

1. `number` is an `int`, it does not implement `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` so you cannot use LINQ on it.
2. **If** you'd have a collection of `int` called `numbers` you could do following:

   ```
   var results = from ans in numbers select ans < 5 ? "false" : "true"  ;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [let clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) to solve your problem.

```
var number = 10;
var result =from ans in youNumbersCollection
        let trueFalse = (number < 5) ? "false" : "true"
        where yourColum = trueFalse;
```

Answer (score 0):

That code makes no sense.  That's not a place for LINQ, which is used to query lists of data.  That code should be simply:

```
var result = number < 5 ? "true" : "false"
```

The contents of a 'where' clause is an expression that evaluates to a bool, just as the contents of an 'if' statement does.  If you were writing a valid LINQ query then the 'where' clause might be something like this:

```
where number < 5
```

Furthermore, you confuse filtering and projection.  The 'where' clause is where you determine whether to include an item in the processing or not and the 'select' clause is where you process it.  Outputting a different result depending on the value of an item is something you do in the 'select' clause, not the 'where' clause, e.g.

```
from item in list
where item.IsActive
select item.Number > 5 ? "true" : "false"
```

That will filter out the items in the list where IsActive is false and only process those where it's true.  For those items not filtered out, it will then output 'true" or "false" based on whether the Number is greater than 5 or not.